# Multiple left outer join with same table allowed?

Tags: sql, performance, join, query-optimization

I tried to convert below SQL in a more optimized way but it is giving error "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int". Could you please help me out

```
select E.EHOId, E.ReferenceId 'ReferenceNo',
(select Comp_Name from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.vCompanyPE where Comp_CompanyId = E.GroupId) 'Group',
(select Comp_Name from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.vCompanyPE where Comp_CompanyId = E.SiteId) 'Site',
 E.VisitDate as 'VisitDate',
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.FollowupAction) 'FollowupAction',
(select Name from EHO_LocalAuthority where ID = E.LocalAuthority) 'LocalAuthority',
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.[Status]) 'Status', 
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.Position) 'Position',
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.Structural) 'Structural',
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.ConfidenceinManagement) 'ConfideninManagement',
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.HygieneandSafety) 'HygieneandSafety',
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.RoutineInspection) 'RoutineInspection',
(select Name from EHO_Dropdowns where ID = E.OutcomeofVisit) 'OutcomeofVisit',
e.OfficerName,e.FoodHygieneRating,e.ManageronDuty,e.Comments,
CASE E.AnnouncedVisit
 When  0 Then 'No'
 When 1 Then 'Yes'
 Else ''
ENd as 'AnnouncedVisit',
(select u.Username from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.CDB_User u where u.UserId = e.CreatedBy ) 'CreatedBy',
(select COUNT(EHOId) from EHO_Attachments where EHOId = E.EHOId) as 'AttachmentCount'
from EHO_Log E
where E.IsActive = 1 AND e.IsDeleted = 0 
Order by E.VisitDate desc
```

You see Above has alot of inner queries and performance will be very bad if there are thousand records. so i tried to get rid of inner queries.

```
select E.EHOId, E.ReferenceId 'ReferenceNo',
(select Comp_Name from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.vCompanyPE where Comp_CompanyId = E.GroupId) 'Group',
(select Comp_Name from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.vCompanyPE where Comp_CompanyId = E.SiteId) 'Site',
 E.VisitDate as 'VisitDate',
F.Name 'FollowupAction',L.Name 'LocalAuthority', St.Name 'Status',
P.Name 'Position', S.Name 'Structural', C.Name 'ConfideninManagement',
H.Name 'HygieneandSafety', R.Name 'RoutineInspection', O.Name 'OutcomeofVisit',
e.OfficerName,e.FoodHygieneRating,e.ManageronDuty,e.Comments,
CASE E.AnnouncedVisit
 When  0 Then 'No'
 When 1 Then 'Yes'
 Else ''
ENd as 'AnnouncedVisit',
(select u.Username from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.CDB_User u where u.UserId = e.CreatedBy ) 'CreatedBy',
(select COUNT(EHOId) from EHO_Attachments where EHOId = E.EHOId) as 'AttachmentCount'
from EHO_Log E
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns St ON St.Id = E.[Status]
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns F ON F.Id = E.FollowupAction
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns L ON L.Id = E.LocalAuthority
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns P ON P.Id = E.Position
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns S ON S.Id = E.Structural
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns C ON C.Id = E.ConfidenceinManagement
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns H ON H.Id = E.HygieneandSafety
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns R ON R.Id = E.RoutineInspection
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns O ON O.Id = E.OutcomeofVisit
where E.IsActive = 1 AND e.IsDeleted = 0 
Order by E.VisitDate desc
```

Above code failed and i thought multiple Left outer joins are not allowed and i converted it into below query but still it fails

```
select E.EHOId, E.ReferenceId 'ReferenceNo',
(select Comp_Name from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.vCompanyPE where Comp_CompanyId = E.GroupId) 'Group',
(select Comp_Name from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.vCompanyPE where Comp_CompanyId = E.SiteId) 'Site',
 E.VisitDate as 'VisitDate',
D.Name 'FollowupAction',D.Name 'LocalAuthority', D.Name 'Status',
D.Name 'Position', D.Name 'Structural', D.Name 'ConfideninManagement',
D.Name 'HygieneandSafety', D.Name 'RoutineInspection', D.Name 'OutcomeofVisit',
e.OfficerName,e.FoodHygieneRating,e.ManageronDuty,e.Comments,
CASE E.AnnouncedVisit
 When  0 Then 'No'
 When 1 Then 'Yes'
 Else ''
ENd as 'AnnouncedVisit',
(select u.Username from FoodAlertCRM.dbo.CDB_User u where u.UserId = e.CreatedBy ) 'CreatedBy',
(select COUNT(EHOId) from EHO_Attachments where EHOId = E.EHOId) as 'AttachmentCount'
from EHO_Log E
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns D ON D.Id = E.[Status] AND D.Id = E.FollowupAction
AND D.Id = E.LocalAuthority AND D.Id = E.Position AND D.Id = E.Structural
AND D.Id = E.ConfidenceinManagement AND D.Id = E.HygieneandSafety
AND D.Id = E.RoutineInspection AND D.Id = E.OutcomeofVisit
where E.IsActive = 1 AND e.IsDeleted = 0 
Order by E.VisitDate desc
```

Any idea guys? both of the new queries return error "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int".

Comment: In what way did the new queries fail? Did they produce errors, and if so what were they? Did they run without errors but fail to produce the required data, and if so in what way were the results at fault?

Comment: Both of the new queries fail and gives me error "Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cause may be this line:

```
Left Outer Join EHO_Dropdowns L ON L.Id = E.LocalAuthority
```

Try changing it to be:

```
Left Outer Join EHO_LocalAuthority L ON L.Id = E.LocalAuthority
```

Comment: Bummer how can i miss this. You are absolutely correct but how did you manage to check it out of all tables. :) can you please tell me is it optimized to use so many left outer rather than inner query? thanks

Comment: It seems that last query which has AND clauses in left outer join fails to produce correct results it gives NULLs and if i do OR then it gives multiple records or double the size. so second is best option?

Comment: @KamranPervaiz: I am inclined to prefer the second query. The only way to be reasonably certain which of these is the better-performing approach would be to try running both queries against realistic datasets and see which performs better. I have seen the sub-query approach used where the author wanted to force the optimizer to use an index on the subqueried table; however, this may prevent the optimizer from using a single table scan where it would be faster than multiple accesses by index. The sub-query approach also may fail if more than one value is ever returned by one of the sub-queries.

Comment: thanks, but it is not showing correct results. All the left outer join result returns NULL or Othername if exists. Although there are corrrect data in the record but it shows NULL? any idea?

Comment: sorry it is now working. there should be an else case in each When statement like Else R.Name etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Mulitple Outer Join on Same Table :

Solution:

please use nvl on outer join fields

```
NVL(EHO_Dropdowns(+),EHO_LocalAuthority(+)) = E.LocalAuthority
```